# Split columns values and move to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database

I want to split and move that data into rows. I have numbers of columns which i need to split and move to rows. Single column data is possible but i have not got the solution for multiple columns.Solution in ms sql or Excel both is acceptable. Please find screen shot.

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: This is a pain to do in any SQL database.  If you can handle this outside of SQL Server, then I would recommend doing that.

Comment: While, in general,  I agree with Tim, still added some direct approach to get an expected result parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `SPLIT_STRING()` does not have an "ordinality" or "indexing" option.  So, you cannot really retrieve the values in a known order.  (In practice, it does return the values in order, but there is no guarantee.)

And, SQL tables and result sets are *unordered*.  So, depending on ordering is a really bad practice, even if the code seems to work.

I recommend using recursive CTEs:

```
with t as (
      select 'prod1' as name, '3,5,6,9' as col1, '33,44,66,7' as col2, '66,7' as col3
     ),
     cte as (
      select name, 1 as lev,
             convert(varchar(max), left(col1, charindex(',', col1 + ',') - 1)) as col1,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(col1, 1, charindex(',', col1 + ','), '')) as col1_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), left(col2, charindex(',', col2 + ',') - 1)) as col2,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(col2, 1, charindex(',', col2 + ','), '')) as col2_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), left(col3, charindex(',', col3 + ',') - 1)) as col3,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(col3, 1, charindex(',', col3 + ','), '')) as col3_rest
      from t
      union all
      select name, lev + 1,
             left(col1_rest, charindex(',', col1_rest + ',') - 1) as col1,
             stuff(col1_rest, 1, charindex(',', col1_rest + ','), '') as col1_rest,
             left(col2_rest, charindex(',', col2_rest + ',') - 1) as col2,
             stuff(col2_rest, 1, charindex(',', col2_rest + ','), '') as col2_rest,
             left(col3_rest, charindex(',', col3_rest + ',') - 1) as col3,
             stuff(col3_rest, 1, charindex(',', col3_rest + ','), '') as col3_rest
      from cte
      where col1_rest <> '' or col2_rest <> '' or col3_rest <> ''
     )
select name, col1, col2, col3
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba1b0a594f1f7581d30baf06c4e42a5d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Some disclaimers:

- `STRING_SPLIT` requires SQL Server 2016+
- `MAXDOP 1` added intentionally

SQL:

```
-- seeding data
DECLARE @data TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(50), Column1  VARCHAR(50), Column2  VARCHAR(50), Column3  VARCHAR(50))
INSERT @data VALUES ('Prod1', '3,5,6,9', '33,44,66,7', '66,7')

-- splitting strings into coluns
;WITH cte_col1 AS (
SELECT Name,
       Col1.value AS ColumnValue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn,
       1 AS ColumnID       
FROM @data d
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.Column1, ',') AS Col1
)
, cte_col2 AS (
SELECT Name,
       Col2.value AS ColumnValue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn,
       2 AS ColumnID
FROM @data d
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.Column2, ',') AS Col2
)
, cte_col3 AS (
SELECT Name,
       Col3.value AS ColumnValue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn,
       3 AS ColumnID
FROM @data d
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.Column3, ',') AS Col3
)

-- gluing all parts together
SELECT 
    d.Name
,   min (CASE WHEN d.ColumnID = 1 THEN d.ColumnValue END ) AS Column1
,   min (CASE WHEN d.ColumnID = 2 THEN d.ColumnValue END ) AS Column2
,   min (CASE WHEN d.ColumnID = 3 THEN d.ColumnValue END ) AS Column3
FROM (
SELECT Name, ColumnValue, rn, cte_col1.ColumnID FROM cte_col1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, ColumnValue, rn, cte_col2.ColumnID FROM cte_col2
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, ColumnValue, rn, cte_col3.ColumnID FROM cte_col3
) d
GROUP BY d.Name, d.rn
ORDER BY d.Name, d.rn
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Results into:

```
Name    Column1 Column2 Column3
Prod1   3   33  66
Prod1   5   44  7
Prod1   6   66  NULL
Prod1   9   7   NULL
```